# Hyperledger Fabric - How to change collection config for chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using Hyperledger Fabric with its Private Data feature. The example of `collection-config.json` is:

```
[
 {
    "name": "collectionMarbles",
    "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 3,
    "blockToLive":1000000
 },
 {
    "name": "collectionMarblePrivateDetails",
    "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 3,
    "blockToLive":3
 }
]
```

With this config, data under `"collectionMarblePrivateDetails"` are accessible only by `Org1MSP.member`.

Now I want to change the accessibility to `Org2MSP.member` only. Is it possible to do something like `$ peer chaincode upgrade --collections-config  $GOPATH/src/github.com/chaincode/marbles02_private/collections_config.json`, so as to update the collection policy? (Tried, but no success with it yet)

Comment: what did you get by running this command?

Comment: i did not get this command. Just wonder how to change the accessibility of private data.

Comment: which version of Fabric are you using?

Comment: @Gari it's Fabric v1.4

Comment: @Harshit `what did you get by running this command?` > I updated only `collectionMarblePrivateDetails` in the config JSON without modifying any of the chaincode. By running this command with other appropriate flags (e.g. a newer version number), the command was accepted and I could query the newer version, yet I could still query only with Org1 (although config JSON has been renewed with Org2 as the only party).

Comment: I dont think that will work, because the collection once created cannot be deleted, lets hope they give a way around for your problem. refer : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data-arch.html#upgrading-a-collection-definition

Comment: if you find a way, plz make sure to update here as well. I would like to know that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the Fabric [private data documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data-arch.html#upgrading-a-collection-definition):

> If a collection is referenced by a chaincode, the chaincode will use
>   the prior collection definition unless a new collection definition is
>   specified at upgrade time. If a collection configuration is specified
>   during the upgrade, a definition for each of the existing collections
>   must be included, and you can add new collection definitions.
>
> Collection updates becomes effective when a peer commits the block
>   that contains the chaincode upgrade transaction. Note that collections
>   cannot be deleted, as there may be prior private data hashes on the
>   channel’s blockchain that cannot be removed.

So yes, it is possible to update the private data collection membership by upgrading the chaincode.

Here is the syntax I use to install a 2nd chaincode version and then upgrade it on the channel with a new collection configuration:

```
peer chaincode install -n marblesp -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/marbles02_private -v 2 
peer chaincode upgrade -C mychannel -n marblesp -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -v 2 -o 127.0.0.1:7050 --collections-config collection.json
```

It looks like you missed some of the upgrade flags.

Any newly added members will receive private data for future transactions. Any removed members will stop receiving private data for future transactions.

Note that as of Fabric v1.4, any newly added members of a private data collection will also automatically receive the private data previously committed to the private data collection via a reconciliation process.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, it works! Seems it was my carelessness.

Comment: is it possible to add new collections when upgrading the chaincode?

Comment: Yes possible, however you need to include all existing collection definitions as well. Keep in mind that you cannot change name or blockToLive attributes. Otherwise your new collection won't become effective (and you won't see any warning on upgrade regarding to this)